# There's a lot of old mines around here

Tags: grammar

> "There's a lot of old mines around here."

This is a line from the beginning of the movie Nevada Smith.
I think the grammatically correct line is,

> "There're a lot of old mines around here."

I think being grammatically correct does not necessarily mean being colloquially natural.

I wonder which is commoner, **"There's a lot of old mines"** or **"there're a lot of old mines"**, colloquially speaking.

Comment: *There's* (note, not *There is*) is special. It's fine here.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AlanCarmack That should be obvious if you read the last sentence that starts with "I wonder".

Answer (score 1):

Regarding grammar rules, what doesn't work for writing or highly formal speaking may sometimes have no bearing on what is used for normal everyday speech. The fact is that the use of *here's* and *there's'* with plural nouns is extremely common and acceptable, informally. And of course, one should be wise to avoid them in careful, formal writing.

Comment: You'll be one of those referenced by *some prescriptivists are bound to take offense at this* in the top answer to what I consider [the original question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/theres-vs-there-are) then.