# How to understand "there's only so many times you can polish a prefect badge" in this context?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> “Percy's been acting very oddly this summer,” said George, frowning. “And he has been sending a lot of letters and spending a load of time shut up in his room… I mean, **there's only so many times you can polish a prefect badge**… You're driving too far west, Fred,” he added, pointing at a compass on the dashboard. Fred twiddled the steering wheel.

The thing I don't quite understand from that sentence:

> What does "**only so many times**" convey exactly? Is it saying Percy
>   didn't get many chances to polish a prefect badge?

-- Excerpted from Harry Potter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There's vs There are](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/theres-vs-there-are)

Comment: You're only supposed to ask *one question per post.* For your second question, the answer is ***Yes***. An utterance such as ***There's only so many ways to skin a cat*** means there are ***a limited number*** (=not very many) ways to do the action specified.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, How about I remove the first one and leave the second one only?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don´t think that the answer to the second question is "yes". "Did Percy get many chances to polish a prefect badge?"  We don't know, that information is not in the quoted text, neither explicitly nor implicitly. Is there a limited number of ways to polish a badge? Yes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I have edited my question. Do you think it's ok now?

Comment: @RubioRic: <sigh> The answer is ***Yes** - What Dan thinks (that Percy didn't get many chances to polish a prefect badge) is **correct***. This idiomatic usage can easily be found in dictionaries - [***only so much/many:***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/only-so-much-many) *used to say that there are limits to something.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks! I haven't found that definition in the dictionaries I have been looking up.

Comment: @RubioRic: Oh, sorry. Looking at the context again I see that Dan has slightly misunderstood exactly ***what*** is being defined as "limited" here. Presumably no-one's actually *preventing* Percy from polishing his badge, so we can't really say he "doesn't get many chances". It's just that after doing it ***some relatively small number of times***, Percy will find that "badge-polishing" loses its novelty value (it will no longer relieve his boredom, make him feel important, or whatever).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's what I meant. Maybe I didn't explain myself clearly.

Comment: @RubioRic: No - you're right. I was only thinking of the meaning of the idiomatic construction ***only so many times** [one can do something]*, and didn't bother to check whether Dan's "restatement" was accurate as regards the precise detail of what was being described as "limited".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "only so much/many" means there's [a limit to what follows](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/only-so-much-many). In this context, George is commenting on how much time Percy is spending alone, and also making a joke about his stuffy attitude; Percy *could*, in George's opinion, amuse himself for a long time just by polishing his prefect badge, but even that can't account for it all, because even Percy would lose interest eventually - there's "only so many times" he can polish it.

Comment: I haven't read out all those implications! Thank you very much!

Comment: Is **polishing** a euphemism perhaps?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo XD We are talking about Harry Potter books here. George is prefect and got an actual badge that he keeps shiny.

Comment: @RubioRic:  Haven't read the books, but I've seen the movies. Isn't George one of the twins, and rather irreverent?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I get your point. Maybe you're right there.