# there is/ are loads of things you can buy

Tags: singular-vs-plural, quantifiers

According to [this website](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/lot-plenty-load-number/), **a lot of**, **lots of**, **a load of** and **loads of** take a singular verb if they refer to an amount of something uncountable and a plural verb if they are followed by a plural countable noun. However, I came across a sentence in an informal dialogue that breaks the rules:

> There's loads of things you can buy.

It's obvious that **things** is countable and in plural form. Why is it **there's** instead of **there are**?

Comment: Slang often breaks the rules.  In proper discussion, you would say "There are loads of things you can buy" (although in actual proper discussion, you would not likely use the idiom "loads of", but something more like "There are a great many things one could buy")

Comment: Just to add, you really would not say "There is loads of things you can buy" even in slang - it's more about making it shorter via the contraction "There's".

Comment: @michael That's a great observation! In informal English *there's* can be followed by a plural noun. See the duplicate target and the answer by Araucaria for more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There's vs There are](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/theres-vs-there-are)