# There's + plural form

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

I often hear native speakers use "There's" instead of "There're", i.e., they just use "There's" regardless of what follows.
e.g. "There's two people."

Is it a current trend? I guess this is caused by people are lazy or not sure about what follows when speaking "there be".

Comment: Yes, it is becoming more common as media and other people simply don't get the grammar. Especially, AmE media people.

Comment: @Lambie I was about to write an answer noting that this usage has long existed in English. Do you have any evidence that it's becoming more common or that it's especially prevalent in American media?

Comment: Compare https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/theres-vs-there-are

Comment: Not a new trend. At school in London 60 years ago, teachers told us not to do it. But we did when they weren't listening. _There's_ is easier to say than _there're_ and _there are_ is sometimes too formal.