# When is "into" correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

We use "in"  when we talk about something with inner structure, literally or metaphorically. We use "to" when we talk about direction, so do we use "into" when we talk about something with inner structure and we are directed to it?

For example:

"Moving in your house" is correct.

But is "Moving into your house" correct?

I guess so because the house has a inner structure and the action move also implies direction. Am I using "into" correctly?

Comment: Yes, you are using "into" correctly. But your example _Moving in your house_ is not correct, at least in standard English. Unless you mean that you are making some movements (no direction) in that house.

Comment: I have heard a American youtuber say to her boyfriend:"Will you move in with me"?Is there a difference?

Comment: There is a difference because no destination is specified so its wrong to use into.

Comment: **Usually** _in_ refers to position (Mary is in the house) and _into_ refers to movement (Mary goes out into the garden). _Move in_ has the specific meaning 'start to live in a place'.

Comment: @Cerise ""Will you **move in with** me"? implies *go to live in my house*.

Comment: The "new house" example gets weird because ***to move in*** is a phrasal verb meaning ***to take up residence***. Which *in principle* I think should lead to *When are you **moving in to** your new house?* (that's what I would write), but apparently that exact sequence doesn't occur at all in Google Books - it's always [*When are you **moving into** your new house?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22when+are+you+moving+into+your+new+house%22) And those are *published* writers, so I guess they and their editors know better than me! :)

Comment: but regardless of that disagreement about orthography (which can't be *heard*), note that you can ask *When are you moving in?*, but you can't ask *When are you moving into?*

Comment: Have you looked up the definition of "into" in a reputable dictionary? If so, what did you find and what are you still confused about? Please [edit] your question with this information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There's vs There are](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/theres-vs-there-are)

Comment: Please put clarification in the question not in the comments. Edit the question! Specifically, do you want to say you are going indoors (in someone else's house, or in a house where you already live), or changing the place where you ordinarily reside, or permanently living with a partner, or some other change? Or do you want to know the difference between the various phrases? If the latter, then list the phrases you want disambiguated (e.g. "move in with someone") *in the question*!

Answer (score 1):

"Moving in your house," means something that is already in the house is moving inside it. For example, [WiFi can detect](https://medium.com/@radiomaze/wifi-signals-enable-motion-recognition-throughout-the-entire-home-5c4dd184627c) something moving in your house."

"Moving into your house," means you've come from somewhere *else* and are relocating to a new abode. Furniture, for example, is being moved *into* the house.

That said, it's paradoxical that we *do* say, "My son moved *in* with us." And there are two prepositions in series, as well. But that is [English as she is spoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_She_Is_Spoke)... it's enough to make one break out in hives.